# Can't uninstall brew postgres

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to run `brew uninstall postgres` but I am getting these errors:

I used to have postgres.app and the enterprise install too.

```
Contents  brew uninstall postgres
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Error: The current working directory doesn't exist, cannot proceed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are running that command from a directory that doesn't exist (or no longer named the wait it appears on the terminal) anymore. Why don't you try `cd .` or `cd "$PWD"` again and trying to run the command once again.

Answer (score 0):

you are running the command in a directory that doesn’t exist, close the terminal and re-open it, or just restart your macOs. Never remove any directory before you restart OS.